# Track point or rect and replace with another mat

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I try to make app like ink hunter, make it to detect object but on live camera overlaped image blink cause every time i detect object again n again in every frame.I read lot about track object but not found any useful algorithm, cause once algorithm i confuse with other algorithm, i very confuse which method or algorithm should i use.
Initially i detect hand written plus sign and get center point of ROI , Now which algorithm should i use to track center point of rect and place image over there.

After detecting plus (+) sign i have to place another image on it, Using copyto() method i place image on it,but cause overlaying image flick every time frame change , So i want once plus sign points are found then track it and place image at the point.
My sample image as below.

[image: Check Image]

```
 Moments m = moments(lrrIMG, true);
 Point point = new Point(m.m10 / m.m00, m.m01 / m.m00);
```

using this code i able to get center point ,Now i have to place image that point and track until it disappear from mobile screen.

Comment: Please add some code and results or source images to be able to understand the problem. Try to be more clear in your question. You can check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: sorry for inconvenience, check question again.

Comment: Why dont you detect your object in everyframe? Detecting it shouldnt take much time.

Comment: The problem here seems to be that the data from camera is being displayed before the image with replaced mat is displayed. If this is indeed the case, the solution would be to disable displaying the video from camera and only show the processed images.

Comment: every time detect object cause flick overlap images on screen,That`s not right way for overlap image.and handwritten plus sign not detect easily in certain circumtance to detect object everyframe not usable.

Comment: @RavitejaNarra how it possilbe to show only proccessed image because if i do this it show only oneframe.